# How should i check if gravatar exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

using this gem 
https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/gravatar
how do i check if gravatar for specified email exist or not? I think i am missing some force default option? Because this

```
url = Gravatar.new("generic@example.com").image_url
```

always return a picture

Comment: Have you tried with an invalid email address other than `generic@example.com` ?

Comment: yeah, i tried, same result :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at that gem's documentation, it sounds like you need an API key before you can run the exists method:

> Fine, but how about the rest of the API as advertised at en.gravatar.com/site/implement/xmlrpc? Well, for that you need either the user’s Gravatar password, or their API key:
>
> api = Gravatar.new("generic@example.com", :api_key => "AbCdEfG1234")
>
> api.exists?("another@example.com")            #=> true or false, depending on whether the specified email exists.

If the user doesn't have a gravatar, an image will be generated for them based on the email (at least that has been my experience). I've used the gem gravatar_image_tag - http://rubygems.org/gems/gravatar_image_tag which lets you change the default gravatar image.

Comment: This is maybe another approach to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103620/gravatar-how-do-i-know-if-a-user-has-a-real-picture?rq=1

Comment: well, i just did not catch the politics gem vs gravatar. As in written in gravatar documentation u can easy pass d= parameter to an image request: 404: do not load any image if none is associated with the email hash, instead return an HTTP 404 (File Not Found) response. That i was looking for in the mentioned gem

Answer (score 46):

In case people would like to know how to do it without any gems :

The trick is to get gravatar image with a false default image and then check header response.
It's achieved with the Net::HTTP ruby library.

```
require 'net/http'

def gravatar?(user)
    gravatar_check = "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.gravatar_email.downcase)}.png?d=404"
    uri = URI.parse(gravatar_check)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    response = http.request(request)
    response.code.to_i != 404 # from d=404 parameter
end
```

Comment: But if email doesn't exists, it doesn't reply with 404, but with the default gravatar, so how could you return false?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what allows you to get an error if there is no gravatar, because you provide a false default picture.

Comment: @ Noémien Kocher  This works great for me on localhost, but when I deploy to Heroku, I get the error 'uninitialized constant Net::HTTP' Does anyone know why?

Comment: @TomD did you try to add "require 'net/http'" at the top of your file ?

Comment: @ Noémien Kocher.  No, I hadn't done that, and adding it as you suggest resolved the issue.  Many thanks!

Comment: also start with `require 'digest'`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (response.code.to_i == 404)
  return false
else
  return true
end
```

Instead of whole block, use only this(as a last line):

```
response.code.to_i != 404
```